# Enabling CORS in Ionic for a PUT/DELETE Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

For my Ionic app I'm using an API that I created that I can make simple HTTP requests to. In my API I enabled CORS by adding the following to server.js:

```
//ENABlE CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

and so my GET and POST requests work just fine. However, my PUT request returns the error " Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response." How can I fix this issue specifically for PUT/DELETE?

Put request in controller.js

```
var link = 'https://cs496-app3.herokuapp.com/api/person/';
   var obj = {
     'name' : $scope.data.name, 
     'email_address': $scope.data.email,
     'location' : $scope.data.location
   };

   var ls = UserProfile.getAll();
   console.log(ls);
   var curProfile = ls[0];
   var prevName = curProfile.name;

   $http.put(link + prevName, JSON.stringify(obj)).then(function (res){
      alert("Successfully updated your account information")
       console.log("put successful");
       $state.transitionTo('tab.profile');

   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your CORS setup in server.js like the following;

```js
//ENABlE CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try installing `npm install cors`, then

```
var express  = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

this will handle all cors issues.

Comment: It's an AngularJS application not node.js.

Comment: My mobile app is an Angular app but my API is built in node

Comment: thats i am guessing. I believe chrome will sent preflight requests for every not so simple http calls which should be allowed by server response. Just try the code I suggested in node, it may help. Enabling Cors in node will handle preflights easily.